# Drupal 7.14 + Superfish menu + Dropdown not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, superfish

I have checked Show as Expanded in the main menu, activated Superfish menu as well in Drupal 7.14 custom theme but the dropdown is not working. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

under Modules>jQuery update>Conifgure! The "Default jQuery Version" is set to 1.9 0r 1.10. Change it to 1.8 and it will work.